# Associate phone with multiple contacts?

Tags: google-contacts, google-voice

In Google Voice/Gmail, I have 3 contacts (my family members) that share a home phone number. I currently have this number associated with a separate contact called Home so that it will show up that way on caller ID.

It seems to me, though that it would be better to have this number associated with the actual people who use it because that more accurately reflects reality. Is it possible to  make this association in Google Contacts and still have the number show up as home on caller ID?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you put the home number in the other 3 members your caller ID will be the first in A-Z order. One trick is to put Home contact as '@Home' so caller ID from home will be the first.

Comment: Thanks, this looks like a good way to do it. I will just wait a little while before accepting to see if anything better shows up.

Comment: I've also seen it as **aaHome** or **aaaHome**.